# can I construct a long list<int> such that the index is long?

Tags: c#

currently the index a `List<int>` can take is Int32, can I go for Int64?

So i can use something like mylist[1000000000000].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No you cannot.

This would not be useful if it was allowed.  The CLR has a limit on the maximum size of an object at 2GB.  Hence it's not even possible to construct an array where a `long` index would be useful.

Comment: I believe Mono uses 64bit ints for array indexes.  I'm not sure if this means their List<> implementation is different though.

Comment: The list could use another strategy to store its items.  For example, it could use some sort of tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the framework List<> interface, which specifies the type of the index argument as `int`.  But you *could* create your own type that takes a `long` index.

As JaredPar noted, you can't make an array that is large enough to require a 64-bit index.  If you want to create a list that can store so many items, you'll have to use some sort of tree structure, or arrays of arrays, or something.  And you'll need a lot of memory!

Answer (score -9):

You can have List that will hold long values, or numbers greater than 2,147,483,647.

```
List<long> list = new List<long>();

list.Add(3000000000) will work.
```

Comment: author meant a collection with a long(int64) index, not a collection of long with an int32 index